# CloudFront Image error when used in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use a CloudFront URL that contains this image I want to use. However, when I use it I get a Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type binary/octet-stream. I'm kinda new to AWS. Is there something I should set in CloudFront?

Comment: What... is D3?  Do you mean S3?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the image in this data visualization library called D3. Thought the error could be there too. Should have made it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

By default S3 will set the mime type of binary/octet-stream.  You can override that by setting your Content-Type of chose on upload.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html